# insert into after insert into with autonumeric

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have to make two insert into like this:

```
INSERT INTO CONVERSATION (issue,...) VALUES ('Presentation',...);
INSERT INTO CONVERSATIONMESSAGES VALUES (ConversationId, 'Hello everybody',...);
```

In the first table the only PK is an autonumeric field (ConversationId) and later I have to know this autonumeric field to insert in the second table.

is there any way to do this? Something like do a select * when Im doing the first Insert to know it for the second Insert?

Thank you very much, I hope I explained correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to insert the last generated *autoincremented* on the table, eg

```
INSERT INTO CONVERSATION (issue,...) VALUES ('Presentation',...);
INSERT INTO CONVERSATIONMESSAGES VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Hello everybody',..);
```

- [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

but this sometimes fail if you have concurrent `INSERT`s.

Try creating a stored procedure for this,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcNAME(...PARAMETERS HERE...)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CONVERSATION (issue,...) VALUES ('Presentation',...);
    SET @lstID = (SELECT MAX(ConversationId) FROM CONVERSATION);
    INSERT INTO CONVERSATIONMESSAGES VALUES (@lstID, 'Hello..',..);
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @retVal as int

INSERT INTO CONVERSATION (issue,...) VALUES ('Presentation',...);

@retval=SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO CONVERSATIONMESSAGES VALUES (ConversationId, 'Hello everybody',...);
```

you will get last inserted row numberic value in @revVal to be used in other table